# Is there a way for me to store the individual letters of a string in a char array?

Tags: c#

I am trying to recreate wordle on C#. After I get the user input, I am trying to store each individual letters of the string into a 2D char array. Below is my code.

```
        // Store words            
        char[,] userWords = new char[6, 5];

        // Ask user for word
        Console.Write("\nGuess a word!: ");

        // Get user words
        for (int i = 0; i < userWords.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < userWords.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                userWords[i, j] = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                
                // Test 
                Console.WriteLine(userWords[i, j]);
                
            }
        }
```

I am assuming that each word I type is being stored in one section of the array, which is why it isn't working. How can I store each letter of each word in the array?

Comment: You read whole line, which is `string`, and you try to store it in `char`. Why do you want `char` matrix instead of array/list/dictionary of `string`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't have the Console.ReadLine() inside the inner for loop as that would require the user to input a word after every iteration of reading the word’s individual letters.

The program now asks for user input after each iteration of "i" so that you can fill the 2D array with 6 words, each 5 letters long.

```
// Store words            
char[,] userWords = new char[6, 5];

// Get CHARS from user's word
for (int i = 0; i < userWords.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    // Ask user for word
    Console.Write("\nGuess a word!: ");

    // Temp store for user's word
    string wordTemp = Console.ReadLine();
    
    for (int j = 0; j < userWords.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        userWords[i, j] = wordTemp[j];

        // Test 
        Console.WriteLine(userWords[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. However, since the for loop says 'int i = 0; i < 1; i++' I can only add one word. Is there any way around that?

Comment: Sorry! I had changed that for testing it. I will edit the code now

Comment: So sorry to ask another question, but when I add those conditions, the characters in the first word fills out the entire word

Comment: No worries. I’m assuming that what you want to do is fill the first dimension of the array with 6 words, in which case you’ll need to move the ReadLine() into the first for loop. I have altered my code above for you.

Comment: @12345678i9 No problem! Would you mind marking this as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure but I'm guessing you want something more like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userWords.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    var word = Console.Readline():
    for (int j=0; j< Math.Min(word.Length, userWords.GetLength(1)); j++)
    {
        userWords[i,j] = word[j];
    }
}
```

Reason: `Console.ReadLine()` return a string, which you can treat as a one-dimensional array of characters by using the [indexer property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're trying to convert a string to a character. Instead, you can use `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` to capture a single character from the user.

Here's a brief example, I'll probably update this tomorrow with a more thoughtful answer, though:

```
// Store words. First dimension is rows, second is columns        
char[,] userWords = new char[6, 5];

// Ask user for word
Console.Write("\nGuess a word: ");

// Get user words
for (int row = 0; row < userWords.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < userWords.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        userWords[row, col] = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    }

    // See if they guessed the correct word here
}
```